# Ant: Convert class name to file path

Tags: ant

**How do I convert Java class names into file paths using Ant tasks?**

For example, given a property containing `foo.bar.Duck` I'd like to get out `foo/bar/Duck.class`.

I tried (and failed) to implement this in terms of `<pathconvert>` and `<regexpmapper>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way, using Ant [resources](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html) and an [`unpackagemapper`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#unpackage-mapper), which is designed for this purpose.  The opposite `package mapper` is also available.

```
<property name="class.name" value="foo.bar.Duck"/>

<resources id="file.name">
  <mappedresources>
    <string value="${class.name}" />
    <unpackagemapper from="*" to="*.class" />
  </mappedresources>
</resources>
```

You use the resource value by means of the property helper syntax `${toString:...}`, e.g.:

```
<echo message="File: ${toString:file.name}" />
```

Yields

```
[echo] File: foo/bar/Duck.class
```

Comment: This solution will work **only and if only** the resource can be found elsewhere. Else, use [@matt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9135198/1099452)'s solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible way to do this:

```
<property name="class.name" value="foo.bar.Duck"/>

<loadresource property="file.name">
  <string value="${class.name}" />
  <filterchain>
    <replaceregex pattern="\." replace="/" flags="g" />
    <replaceregex pattern="$" replace=".class" />
  </filterchain>
</loadresource>
```

This puts the desired `foo/bar/Duck.class` into the `file.name` property.

Answer (score 0):

I feel using ant script-javascript for this is much simpler

```
        <property name="class.name" value="foo.bar.duck" />
        <script language="javascript">
            var className = project.getProperty("class.name");
            println("before: " + className);
            var filePath= className.replace("\\", "/");
            println("File Path: "+filePath);
            project.setProperty("filePath", filePath);              
        </script>
        <echo message="${filePath}" />
```

*note: that naming your variable same as argument e.g var wsPath may give error, it gave to me!*

courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099717/4979331