# Ant propertyregex task to replace special character in string

Tags: maven, ant

My string is `C:\tools\jenkins\HOME\workspace\MAL1793_Driver_DIO`

I want to replace windows-style directory path `"\"` with UNIX style path `"/"`

I have used an Ant propertyregex task in my pom file to achieve this as below.

```
<execution>
    <id>ReplaceWSPath</id>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
    <tasks>
        <echo>"Updating workspace path"</echo>
        <propertyregex 
        property="WSPath"
        input="C:\tools\jenkins\HOME\workspace\MAL1793_Driver_DIO"
        regexp="\"
        replace="/"
        global="true" />
        <echo>"workspace Path = ${WSPath}"</echo>
    </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
    <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

But after execution I am getting this error:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type propertyregex
[ERROR] Cause: The name is undefined.
[ERROR] Action: Check the spelling.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I am using Ant version 1.7.  Are there any settings missing?

Comment: Can you share your final maven configuration?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<propertyregex>` task is not part of Ant, it's part of the third-party [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) collection of Ant tasks.  The error message you quote indicates that you're at least missing the `<taskdef>` needed to use Ant-Contrib in your buildfile.

Instructions on how to set up and use Ant-Contrib are available at [SourceForge](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net):

> First you must install Apache Ant itself, most of the Ant-Contrib
>   tasks require Ant 1.5 or higher to work properly. You can download Ant
>   from [Apache](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi).
>
> Ant-contrib releases are available at the [downloads](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=36177) page. Mailing
>   lists, CVS and bug trackers can be accessed from the [project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib) page.
>
> See the cc tasks for installation instructions for cpptasks. To
>   install ant-contrib:
>
> 1. Copy ant-contrib-0.3.jar to the lib directory of your Ant
>      installation. If you want to use one of the tasks in your own project,
>      add the lines
>
>    `<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>`
>
> to your build file.
>
> 2. Keep ant-contrib-0.3.jar in a separate location. You now have to
>      tell Ant explicitly where to find it (say in /usr/share/java/lib):
>
>    `<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
>       <classpath>
>         <pathelement location="/usr/share/java/lib/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>
>       </classpath>
>      </taskdef>`

You might consider using the built-in Ant [`<pathconvert>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task as an alternative to the `<propertyregex>` if you don't already have Ant-Contrib or need it for anything else in your build.

Answer (score 0):

I feel using ant script-javascript for this is much simpler

```
        <property name="wsPath" value="C:\tools\jenkins\HOME\workspace\MAL1793_Driver_DIO" />
        <script language="javascript">
            var wsPath_BackSlash = project.getProperty("wsPath");
            println("before: " + wsPath_BackSlash);
            var wsPath_FrwdSlash= wsPath_BackSlash.replace("\\", "/");
            println("wsPath_FrwdSlash: "+wsPath_FrwdSlash);
            project.setProperty("wsPath", wsPath_FrwdSlash);                
        </script>
        <echo message="${wsPath}" />
```

*note: that naming your variable same as argument e.g var wsPath may give error, it gave to me!*

courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099717/4979331